# Monotouch UIViewController release method

Tags: uiviewcontroller, mono, xamarin.ios, profiler

As many of you might now, yesterday the new version of Monotouch was released and it includes a very useful and much needed memory profiler. I'm using it to fine tune my app. What I am trying now, is to make sure that the reference count is not increasing constantly on any of my objects.

So my question to any monotouch/cocoa gurus is this: Let's say I have a child UIViewController that I regularly present through my main view controller. If the reference count for the child view controller is constantly 1 even after I repeat the process of presenting it and hiding it a few times, does this mean I am out of the woods?

In other words, is this the only thing I should take care of in order to allow monotouch/ios to do proper garbage collection and not hog the device's memory? I am asking because the TOTAL MEMORY as reported in the profiler is increased with each presentation, even though the reference count of the child view controller does not increase.

The child view controller uses a lot of UIImage, loaded with UIImage.FromBundle

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely UIImage.FromBundle. This method will cache the image for the lifetime of the application (which seems to match your description of how memory just increases).

Comment: I would think that it caches the actual image bytes so that it does not load it again next time from the file system. So this should not make the memory increase each time... But I'll try UIImage.FromFileUncached anyway

Comment: Yes, maybe I was unclear, but if you specify the same bundle you'll get the same image (it won't be reloaded).